# Half power keeps going out

Tags: electrical, appliances

I have a bad door switch in the ac/heater unit. Have had to wiggle it to make heat come on. Today it sparked and half power in the house went out. When I tried to test the dryer everything came back on for about 15 minutes. The has happened twice now. Starting the dryer turns everything back on... What do I do?

Comment: Is there a pattern to which circuits come on and go out relative to the breakers in your breaker box?

Comment: Haven't tested them all for a pattern. Just noticed most of the house being out. Fridge works but oven doesn't they're next to each other. Living room plugs are down but ceiling fan lights are on. All lights upstairs are out except bathroom. Weird combos like this. Happened twice about 15 min apart and turning on dryer reset everything both times. Hasn't happened again yet.

Comment: Is the oven gas or electric, and do you have a clue which breakers in your panel go with which circuits?

Comment: Oven is electric. The breakers are not marked. I would have to check them one at a time.

Answer (score 6):

### I suspect you're losing a leg of your service

The behavior you talk about (multiple disparate circuits out, but turning 240V appliances back on fixes them) is symptomatic of a failing hot leg on the incoming service.  I'd start by calling your electric utility and telling them you have a partial power outage -- their linesman should be able to figure things out rather quickly when they arrive.

Comment: hey, only Harper is allowed to write big bold headings about lost service legs (especially neutral)!

Comment: @user253751 actually, I got the habit from ThreePhaseEel :)

Comment: and OP, I should note, this failure has nothing to do with the problem you are observing, and the power company will fix it for free as 98% chance it's on their side.  240V circuits can really "muddy the water" with this particular failure, since a 240V load coming on will "seem to" re-energize the dead side.